# A few questions about a Lobel-Page critical note

Tags: greek, abbreviations, sappho

In a critical note by Lobel-Page, I read:

> κάλαις ὔμμιν cod. A, quo retento τὸ νόημ[μα] ci. Bekker. quod quamvis cum grammatici verbis aptius congruere videatur, tamen ob ν ἐφελκυστικόν positionem effecturum recipere noluimus

Questions about this:

1. What does "ci." stand for?
2. Does the period after "Bekker.", given the absence of a following capital, mean the name is not Bekker but Bekker+something else hidden in the period? And if so, why does Campbell not have the period? And if not, what is the point of the period? Was a capitalization forgotten?
3. Does "cod. A" mean that there is another codex or more going like cod. B and so on?
4. Why is the "nu ephelkystikon positionem effecturum" an objection to the Bekker emendation?

Answer (score 4):

1. coniecit. It is Bekker's conjecture.
2. He seems not to use a capital at the start of a sentence.
3. yes. It should be explained somewhere what these codices are.
4. He is saying that Bekker's emendation does not scan properly.

Comment: How does it not scan properly? I mean, the nu does make the iota long as it should be, and the rest scans, so it seems the problem is precisely the fact the movable nu is used to make the syllable it ends long by position, but why is that a problem?

Comment: Btw maybe I should have included the fragment we're talking about, it's Sappho LP 41 and in transliteration it reads "Tais kalais ymmin <to> noēmma tōmon / oy diameipton" in Bekker's emendation, and "Tais kalaisin ymmi etc." in Lobel-Page's text.

Comment: He seems to mean that nu ephelkystikon cannot be used to make position, but I would need to check on that.

Comment: I wonder why he thinks so...

Comment: Smyth (135) says "To make a syllable long by position (144) the poets add ν before words beginning with a consonant". But he doesn't say who "the poets" are -- maybe there are no such uses in Sappho/Aeolic poets/archaic poets? That would seem to be the only plausible grounds for the rejection.

Comment: @TKR I guess it would have to be at least "Aeolic poets", unless Alcman doesn't count as archaic, since [here](https://scaife.perseus.org/reader/urn:cts:greekLit:tlg0082.tlg001.1st1K-grc1:111-120?q=ymmin&qk=form) we have «καὶ κῆνοϲ ἐν ϲάλεϲϲιν πολλοῖϲ ἥμενοϲ,» attributed to him. But maybe that is just one that must be dropped because it is pointless and in fact perhaps anti-metrical? I mean, that looks like iambic trimeters to me, and the scheme should be x–u–x–u–x–u–, meaning that position is made on a syllable that should be short…

Comment: @MickG That does look like an error of some kind.